# Print out summaries in console

Tags: python, tensorflow, protocol-buffers, tensorboard

Tensorflow's *scalar/histogram/image_summary* functions are very useful for logging data for viewing with tensorboard. But I'd like that information printed to the console as well (e.g. if I'm a crazy person without a desktop environment).

Currently, I'm adding the information of interest to the fetch list before calling *sess.run*, but this seems redundant as I'm already fetching the merged summaries. Fetching the merged summaries returns a protobuf, so I imagine I could scrape it using some generic python protobuf library, but this seems like a common enough use case that there should be an easier way.

The main motivation here is encapsulation. Let's stay I have my model and training script in different files. My model has a bunch of calls to *tf.scalar_summary* for the information that useful to log. Ideally, I'd be able to specify whether or not to additionally print this information to console by changing something in the training script **without changing the model file**. Currently, I either pass all of the useful information to the training script (so I can fetch them), or I pepper the model file with calls to *tf.Print*

Comment: does tf.Print do what you want?  https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops.html#Print
(note its semantics - data has to flow through it to get it to be invoked)

Comment: Yeah, I've been using that as well, but just for debugging. I don't think its a proper solution, as you're still having to specify what you want to log twice (i.e. in the tf.Print() and in the tf.scalar_summary() ). tf.Print is also cumbersome when you only want to print things periodically (e.g. loss every 10 epochs)

Comment: Concur - thanks for clarifying, was just trying to zoom in a bit more on what your goal was.  (I still have print(every_n=..) on my wishlist.  Some day.)  I can't think of a way to do what you want, but I'll point the author of some of the summary stuff here.

Comment: Do you want to print out every tag, or just a certain sublist?

Comment: @danmane Ideally arbitrary sublists. The functionality of tf.train.summary_iterator is pretty much what I want, but that only works on the event *file*, which can't be opened since you're constantly writing to it. https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/train.html#summary_iterator

Answer (score 2):

Overall, there isn't first class support for your use case in TensorFlow, so I would parse the merged summaries back into a tf.Summary() protocol buffer, and then filter / print data as you see fit.

If you come up with a nice pattern, you could then merge it back into TensorFlow itself. I could imagine making this an optional setting on the tf.train.SummaryWriter, but it is probably best to just have a separate class for console-printing out interesting summaries.

If you want to encode into the graph itself which items should be summarized and printed, and which items should only be summarized (or to setup a system of different verbosity levels) you could use the `Collections` argument to the summary op constructors to organize different summaries into different groups. E.g. the `loss` summary could be put in collections `[GraphKeys.SUMMARIES, 'ALWAYS_PRINT']`, but another summary could be in collection `[GraphKeys.SUMMARIES, 'PRINT_IF_VERBOSE']`, etc. Then you can have different `merge_summary` ops for the different types of printing, and control which ones are run via command line flags.